# Munin 'Unknown option: snmpauthprotocol'

Tags: snmp, munin

I am trying to set the SNMP authentication protocol to SHA to connect to my CISCO switch. When I run:

```
sudo munin-node-configure --snmp SWITCH01 --snmpversion 3 --snmpauthprotocol sha --snmpusername munin --snmpauthpass PASSWORD
```

I am getting the error:

```
Unknown option: snmpauthprotocol
```

It does say in the manual that the option is available:

```
--snmpauthprotocol <protocol>
           Authentication protocol.  One of 'md5' or 'sha' (HMAC-MD5-96, RFC1321 and SHA-1/HMAC-SHA-96, NIST FIPS PIB 180, RFC2264).  ['md5']
```

I could change the protocol on the switch ... If I hadn't accidentally denied ssh access for myself ... I don't feel like taking a 2 hour drive today :/

Just as an extra note, if I run it without the `--snmpauthprotocol` and with `--debug` I get:

```
Received usmStatsWrongDigests.0 Report-PDU with value 4 during synchronization
```

So, I definitely can't use md5 ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just downloaded munin 2.0.25 and looked at the source. Try using `--snmpauthproto` instead of `--snmpauthprotocol`.

Yes, the help text is wrong. <strike>I'll probably open an issue here: https://github.com/munin-monitoring/munin/issues</strike>. I have put in a pull request to correct the typo in the code https://github.com/munin-monitoring/munin/pull/510 which has now been encorportated into the github code and may be included in release 2.1.13 .

Comment: You're right :D ... Unfortunately it's still not working for me ... I decided to have a delve into the source as well (Even though I've never used Perl, so it was an experience) ... I was trying to ensure `sha` was being passed correctly, and not always defaulting to `md5` ... That bit is working correctly, so it's now something I have to fix on my switch Lol ... Also it took me a while to track down how the `--snmpauthproto` switch is being passed to `NET::SNMP`, because the reference name changes about 20 times, from `snmpauthproto` to `snmp3authproto`, `authproto`, `authprotocol` etc ...

Comment: Maybe that's something that could be looked at too :D

Comment: If you need to delve into Perl source in the future for stuff like this, I can recommend this cool debugger called [Devel::Trepan](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Trepan)

Comment: Nice, might take a look when I start learning Perl lol ... Is that your creation?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
  sudo munin-node-configure --snmp SWITCH01 --snmpversion 3 --snmpauthproto md5 --snmpusername munin --snmpauthpass PASSWORD
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: Nope, `--snmpauthproto sha256` doesn't work ... I tried `--snmpauthproto sha-I-Like-Cheese` too, same result.